# "closed as exact duplicate by" - suggestion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, exact-duplicates, hyperlinks

When a question is closed by a moderator as a duplicate, I believe that a reference should be made within the area below that states where the original Q/A resides.

> ### closed as exact duplicate by Fred, Wilma, Barney♦ 1 hour ago
>
> This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question.
>
> [Link to original question goes here](http://meta.superuser.com)

Comment: You mean in addition to the added blockquote at the start of the question automatically put there?

Comment: @random - As indicated in my post above. Most questions just get closed with no reference to the original question that was duplicated. I understand there are tools like the search, etc. but I think we are all here to help, more so the moderators and if they think that the question is a duplicate of another that it would be their responsibility to share the original question/answer so the asker of the duplicate is not left to search until he/she finds it.

Comment: If your searching for the duplicate when as the screenshots below shows all duplicates are added into the actual question at the very top, you should consider having your eyes tested.

Comment: `Most questions just get closed with no reference to the original question that was duplicated` - I'm sorry - but WHAT ?

Comment: @Diago - All rudeness aside, that is not the case with many closed questions.

Comment: @Sathya - Ok maybe this wording is easier to understand: A user submits a question. Question is deemed duplicate and closed. No link to the **ORIGINAL** question was provided. In most cases. Diago seems to be the exception when he closes a question.

Comment: @ricbax: Please put some links highlighting `No link to the ORIGINAL question was provided.` - If true, that's a bug. The original question link is inserted every time,automatically by the system, and the links are fetched from the people who have submitted the close votes

Comment: @Sathya - Definitely will do that. It should probably be instaneous when the question is closed? Maybe there is a delay and I am seeing it before it happens? Either way, I will monitor and let you know here.

Comment: @ricbax: Yes it happens soon as question is closed. If there's an edge case where  you opened the question and then it was closed, you will need a page refresh.

Comment: The only scenario the link will not be there, is if someone edited and removed the link after it was closed. I am not an exception, it is the way the system has worked since the very first time duplicate closing was introduced more then 2 years ago on all the sites, and has been like that since the day Super User launched. As @Sathya points out, if this is not the case, then you need to flag and we will roll it back to show it, I have done a quick check of 25 randomly closed question which are duplicates, and all of them have the link.

Comment: I have since monitored this and it must have been a few recently closed duplicates. I have checked and most duplicates do have a section linking to it as indicated in the answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/202053/portable-virtual-machine-without-admin-priviliges-closed)
[image]

or like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/201990/windows-keyboard-for-mac-closed)?

[image]

Comment: +1 for <s>hand</s>mouse-drawn circles; -1 for JPEG screenshots.